# Required field validator is not working

Tags: asp.net

I have used a *required field validator*, on click of add Button error message will be displayed but whatever code written on onclick event will be executed even if the field is empty.

```
<div class="form-group posrel">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtDept"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDept" placeholder="Department Name" ValidationGroup="ss1"></asp:TextBox>
    <div class="text-right validators">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Department Name" ControlToValidate="txtDept" ValidationGroup="ss1">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the code snippet of add button -

```
<div class="form-group pull-right">
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkbtnaddept" CssClass="btn btn-primary"  ValidationGroup="ss1" OnClick="lnkbtnaddept_Click">
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Add" ID="lbladddept"></asp:Label>
        <i style="margin-left: 10px;" class="fa fa-send"></i>
    </asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this will help you out:
On link-button click event validate your page.

```
Page.Validate("validation group");
if(Page.isValid){
// your code logic
}
```

for more on page validate follow the link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ke7bxeh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Turn on JS support for the Validator control by adding attribute:

```
EnableClientScript="True"
```

It should prevent a post-back until text box is filled.

Answer (score 0):

take your Id of RequiredFieldValidator and update on back end 
or .cs page.

Ans RequiredCityName.Update();